# Paypal token null, One step chekout Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

Hi I'm building a custom checkout page using the one step checkout methods.

```
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('guest');
$checkout->saveBilling($billingAddress, false);
$checkout->saveShipping($billingAddress, false);
$checkout->saveShippingMethod($postData['shipping']['method']);
$checkout->savePayment($postData['payment']);
$checkout->saveOrder();
```

It works correctly with check/money and after a few adjustments with authorize.net, but with paypal using the express checkout(this the one I need) after checking in the model files I see that the token is null.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php
```

Those are the files I tracked while doing the process.

Using the regular chekout(the one that comes with magento not my custom one) I can made a paypal order without any problem.

Is there another way using the magento build in functionality to make the paypal order? or anyone had this issue before and know what is going on?

Comment: there are n OneStepCheckout extensions available and all are paid extension, please contact extension support with such questions

Comment: I think I didn't explain correctly, it is not an extension is just a custom checkout page that I'm building with a custom order create where I'am using the code I paste where $postData is the info from the checkout

Comment: then your information is not ful and you should post your code for analysis and explain that this is your own creation. Start with tracing where the value is set or lost.

Comment: Did you set Paypal's token in System/Configuration/Sales/Payment Methods?